# Find sum of the Trignomertric series

Tags: trigonometric-series

Q1:  The sum of the infinite series $\cot ^{-1}2 + \cot ^{-1} 8+ \cot^{-1}18+ \cot^{-1}32\cdots$

1.$\pi/3$

2.$\pi/4$

3.$\pi/2$

4.None

Q2:  Value of $\lim_ {n \to \infty}[ {\cos \frac{\pi}{2^2} } {\cos
\frac{\pi}{2^3} } \ldots{\cos \frac{\pi}{2^n} }$]

1. $\pi$
2. $1/\pi$
3. $2/\pi$
4. $\pi/e$

Comment: I guess you expect someone to edit your question and make it readable.

Comment: I don't know how to edit my question...I tried my best to write.

Comment: @user19945: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what are your thoughts; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Consider editing you question. Use this$\LaTeX$ guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Shouldn't that 18 in the first line be a 16? Otherwise I don't understand how that series is formed.

Comment: No, its 18..Its the question from an entrance exam..Can't say if its wrong..

Comment: In case its 16 instead of 18 then how to solve this type of series

Comment: @DonAntonio If it's 18 then the sequence is $2n^2$.

Comment: Thanks, @MJD .Only now that's clear to me...

Answer (score 3):

$(2)$ Applying $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x,$ 
$$T_n=\prod_{2\le r\le n}\cos \frac{\pi}{2^r}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\prod_{2\le r\le n-1}\cos \frac{\pi}{2^r}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}}{2\cdot2\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\prod_{2\le r\le n-2}\cos \frac{\pi}{2^r}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{n-3}}}{2^3\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\prod_{2\le r\le n-3}\cos \frac{\pi}{2^r}$$

$$****$$

$$=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{n-s}}}{2^s\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\prod_{2\le r\le n- s}\cos \frac{\pi}{2^r}\text{ where } 0\le s\le n-2$$

Putting $s=n-2,$ $$T_n=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{2}}}{2^{n-2}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\prod_{2\le r\le 2}\cos \frac{\pi}{2^r}=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{2}}}{2^{n-2}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{2\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\cos\frac{\pi}{4}}{2^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}=\frac1{2^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n}}$$

Putting $2^n=\frac1y$ as $n\to\infty\implies  y\to0$

So, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{2\le r\le n}\cos \frac{\pi}{2^r}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2y}{\sin \pi y}=\frac2\pi\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\pi y}{\sin \pi y}=\frac2\pi$$

$(1)$   Assuming the $m$th term to be $\text{arccot}(2m^2)$

This is probably how Marvis found the Telescopic sum form of arccot$(2m^2)$

$$\text{ As arccot}x-\text{arccot}y=\text{arccot}\left(\frac{xy+1}{y-x}\right)$$
$$\text{arccot}(2m^2)=\text{arccot}\frac{m+1}m-\text{arccot}\frac m{m-1} $$

The rest is like his solution.

Comment: @user1709828, I'm trying to identify whether there is any general formula to determine the telescopic sum form. A similar problem : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193001/explicitly-finding-the-sum-of-arctan1-n2n1

Answer (score 1):

For 1, I don't think it is clear what the series is, so would pick 4.

For 2, $\cos \pi=-1$so the numerator is $(-1)^n$ and the denominator gets huge, so the limit is $0$

Comment: @RosMilikan, I found the limit to be $\frac2\pi$ in my answer

Comment: Apparently, the coeffitients of 1. are $2*n^2$ (found using oeis). However, that is not definite.

Comment: @CBenni, could you please have a look into my answer?

Comment: For the second, it has changed from $\frac{\cos \pi}{2^n}$ to $\cos \frac \pi{2^n}$

Answer (score 1):

For the first one,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m} \text{arccot}(2n^2) = \text{arccot} \left(\dfrac{m+1}m\right)$$
Your sum is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \text{arccot}(2n^2) = \lim_{m \to \infty}\text{arccot} \left(\dfrac{m+1}m\right) = \dfrac{\pi}4$$

For the second one,
$$\prod_{k=1}^m \cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2^{k+1}} \right) = \dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)}{2^{m}\sin \left(\dfrac{\theta}{2^{m+1}} \right)}$$
Hence, your product is
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{k+1}} \right) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)}{2^{m}\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{m+1}} \right)} = \dfrac2{\pi}$$

---

For the first one, recall $$\cot(A+B) = \dfrac{\cot(A) \cot(B) - 1}{\cot(A) + \cot(B)}$$
\begin{align}
\cot \left(\text{arccot}\left(\dfrac{m}{m-1}\right) + \text{arccot}\left(2m^2 \right)\right) & = \dfrac{\dfrac{m}{m-1} \cdot 2 \cdot m^2-1}{\dfrac{m}{m-1} + 2 \cdot m^2}\\
& = \dfrac{2m^3-m+1}{2m^3-2m^2+m}\\
& = \dfrac{(m+1)(2m^2-2m+1)}{m(2m^2-2m+1)}\\
& = \dfrac{m+1}m
\end{align}
Now use the above two along with induction to conclude what you want.

For second one, recall $\sin(2 \phi) = 2 \sin(\phi) \cos(\phi)$ and induction to conclude what you want.

Comment: how did you obtain the very first identity?

Comment: In both first and second case?

Comment: @user1709828,for the second case, you may have a look into my answer.