# Sum of infinite terms of $\cot^{-1}(2)+\cot^{-1}\bigl(\frac{9}{2}\bigr)+\cot^{-1}(8)+\cot^{-1}\bigl(\frac{25}{2}\bigr)+\cot^{-1}(18)+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

How can we find sum of infinite terms of the series: 
$$\cot^{-1}(2)+\cot^{-1}\biggl(\frac{9}{2}\biggr)+\cot^{-1}(8)+\cot^{-1}\biggl(\frac{25}{2}\biggr)+\cot^{-1}(18)+ \dots$$

The difference of argument is in A.P. but it does not seem to be valuable. Could someone provide some hint?

Comment: I don't understand what follows after the dots.

Comment: This looks similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326590/find-sum-of-the-trignomertric-series/326650#326650.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

The series can be written

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \text{arccot}\left(\frac{n^2}{2}\right) \tag 1$$

Then, note that

$$\text{arccot}(x)=\frac1x+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \tag 2$$

as $x\to \infty$

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that the series converges by comparison with $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$.  Then, we can write the summands as $$\text{arccot}\left(\frac{n^2}{2}\right)=\text{arccot}\left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)-\text{arccot}\left(\frac{n}{n-2}\right)$$which provides a telescoping series.  To evaluate the limit, we have $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\text{arccot}\left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)-\text{arccot}\left(\frac{n}{n-2}\right)\right)&=\text{arccot}\left(\frac{N+2}{N}\right)\\\\&+\text{arccot}\left(\frac{N+1}{N-1}\right)\\\\&-\text{arccot}\left(3\right)\\\\&\to \frac{\pi}{2}-\text{arccot}(3)\,\,\text{as}\,\,N\to \infty\end{align}$$

Comment: This clearly gives the asymptotic behavior, but does it in fact yield the exact sum (if it converges)?

Comment: @BrianTung It obviously converges by the comparison test.  To find the sum, one needs to use the hint and telescope.

Comment: Sorry, I knew it converged; I was trying not to divulge that.

Comment: @BrianTung No need to apologize.  The initial hint was not clear enough so I added a new section. -Mark

Answer (score 6):

Similarly as in [Find sum of the Trignomertric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326590/find-sum-of-the-trignomertric-series), you can use the identity
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\arccot(x) - \arccot(y) = \arccot\left(\frac{xy+1}{y-x}\right) 
$$
to conclude that
$$
 \arccot \frac{n+2}{n} - \arccot \frac{n}{n-2} = \arccot \frac{n^2}{2}
$$
which allows to write your series as a sum of two telescoping series.