# I need awesome trigonometric inverse problems

Tags: trigonometry

i was just practicing my trigonometry. And i always find finding value of trigonometric inverse functions without a calculator to be hard. Can you guys give me questions to work with? For example, finding $\theta$ such that $$\theta = \arctan(2-\sqrt3)$$
Thanks in advance. Don't go easy on me :)

Comment: Find $\arctan1+\arctan2+\arctan3$.

Comment: It is hard,and it almost not meant to be done by hand,almost never.

Answer (score 1):

To name just a few..

- [Evaluate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28arctan%284%29%29) $\sin(\arctan(4))$
- [Find](http://mymathforum.com/algebra/1323-very-hard-inverse-trig-problem.html) the inverse of $1 + 2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3(t+1)}\right)$
- [Prove](http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-jruiz8/beamer/TrigPresentation/trigpresentation_1.pdf) $\arctan(a) + \arctan(b) = \begin{cases}
  \arctan \left(\frac{a+b}{1-ab}\right),  & ab < 1 \\
  \arctan \left(\frac{a+b}{1-ab}\right) + \pi, & ab > 1, a,b > 0 \\
  \arctan \left(\frac{a+b}{1-ab}\right) - \pi, & ab > 1, a,b < 0
  \end{cases}$
- [Find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193001/explicitly-finding-the-sum-of-arctan1-n2n1) $\sum_{n=1}^{m}\arctan\left({\frac{1}{{n^2+n+1}}}\right)$

More to be added, stay tuned!