# Problem with finding sum of arccot series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometric-series

I have to find $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{arccot}(n^2-n+1)$$ and trying to compute sum of this series. I'm trying to take the derivative of member of the series and compute another sum, but this is not very successful.

Is it right way to try take the derivative or it is useless in this situation? I can't see how to simplify this monster.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193001/explicitly-finding-the-sum-of-arctan1-n2n1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $ \cot^{-1}(x) = \tan^{-1}(1/x)$ and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan^{-1}(A)-\tan^{-1}(B) =\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{A-B}{1+AB} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cot^{-1}(n^2-n+1) &=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{n^2-n+1} \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan^{-1} \frac{n-(n-1)}{1+n(n-1)} \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right) +\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \right)= \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

### HINT

$$\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{1+AB}{A-B}\right)=\cot^{-1}A-\cot^{-1}B.$$

Set $A=n$ and $B=n-1$.